# Check id and then redirect to another page using ajax, codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form include 1 textbox and a message label, which to view the information of patient. User will put the input to the textbox and hit "enter", if input is empty or unavailable id, the system will return to message lable:"Not Found! Try again...", if the input is the available id, redirect to view patient page.
My code is not working, don't show error message and don't redirect.

Here's my controller:

```html
public function checkID()
    {
        require 'application/config/database.php';
        $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : false;

        $conn = mysqli_connect($db['default']['hostname'], $db['default']['username'], $db['default']['password'], $db['default']['database'])
        or die ('{error:"bad_request"}');
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, 'select count(*) as count from patient where PID = \"'.  addslashes($id).'"');

        $error = array(
            'error' => 'Success'
        );

        if (!$id){
            $error['error'] = 'Not Found! Try again...';
            die ('{error:"bad_request"}');
        }

        if ($query){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if ((int)$row['count'] == 0){
                $error['error'] = 'Not Found! Try again...';
            }
            elseif ((int)$row['count'] > 1) {
                $error['error'] = 'Not Found! Try again...';
            }
        }

        die (json_encode($error));
    }
```

Here's my ajax function:

```js
function checkSearchText(e, obj) {
    var reg = /[\<\>\.\'\"\:\;\|\{\}\[\]\,\=\+\-\_\!\~\`\(\)\$\#\@\^\&\,\?]/;
    if (String(obj.value).match(reg)) {
        obj.value = '';
    }
    if ((e.which == 13)) {
        // var res =
        $.ajax({
            url: "checkID",
            global: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if($.trim(result.error) != '' && $.trim(result.error) != 'Not Found! Try again...') {
                    self.document.location = 'view/' + obj.value;
                }
                else {
                    $('#errmsg').append(result.error);
                    $('#errmsg').style = 'color: #FF0000';
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my form:

```html
<form method='post' action>";
    <input class='input' placeholder='Eg.44531' type='text' autofocus id='id' name='id' onkeyup=checkSearchText(event,this);>
    <div id='errmsg' >Type Patient ID and hit ENTER</div>";
</form>";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: don't compare errors by their message (like you did in your ajax call), use codes instead.
Btw, whats your problem? this code don't redirects? you forgot to tell us whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well If you are using CodeIgniter why not use form validation class and other features?

In your controller:

```
public function checkID(){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'Patient ID', 'callback_check_id');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this-load->view('myForm');
    }else{
        // CI does all the work for form validation
        // Validation runs so you can redirect
    }
}

// Callback function to check ID
public function check_id($id)
{
    if (/*$id does not exist in database*/){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_id', 'Not Found! Try again...');
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

and your view file (called "myForm" in controller):

```
<?php
$id = array(
    'name'  => 'id',
    'id'    => 'id',
    'value' => set_value('id'),
    'type'  => 'text',
    'class' => 'input',
    'placeholder' => 'Eg.44531',
);
?>

<?php echo form_open('yourController/checkID'); ?>
    <?php echo form_input($id); ?>
    <?php echo form_error($id['name']); ?><?php echo isset($errors[$id['name']])?$errors[$id['name']]:''; ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Lets check this ID'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The code snippet is from top of my head, not tested and you have to add query to check for ID existance in database (suggest to use [CI query builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/index.html))

For better understanding how code snippet works [CodeIgniter form validation library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods)
and [CodeIgniter Form Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)